# How to edit _vimrc file?

Tags: vim

I am having trouble saving my settings on vim. I know that in order to do that I need to open the `vimrc` file but when I do that it says that the file is *readonly* and won't let me edit it, preventing me from saving my settings.

It says that in order to force save it or *override* it, I need to add the `!` mark after `:w` in the command section, which I do, but it still does not work.

I can't find any other solution to this problem.

Note: I am using Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, you may need to run your editor as administrator to write to your system's `_vimrc` file.

You may also create a `_vimrc` in your home directory (e.g. `C:\Users\Piet\_vimrc`, see the output of `:echo $HOME`) without administrator access.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it this way:

Instead of `:w`, type `:w !sudo tee %`. I guess it should work.

(my answer is based on [this tutotial](http://www.geekyboy.com/archives/629) where the whole problem is well-described)

Answer (score 1):

You may be editing the one global vimrc in /etc/vimrc to which you don't have access.

Make sure you're editing ~/.vimrc and check that you have read and write priviledges to the file (`ls -l ~/.vimrc`). Since the file is in your home folder you should have those privilages but it won't hurt to verify.